# How to rotate static model in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

How would I rotate a static model in XNA? The model is loaded into a separate class called 'ModelManager':

I needed to rotate the model called 'track_new' but it is stored as a whole with other models. Would the rotation go under the 'modelManager' class or the main 'Game!.cs' file?

Here is my code:

```
public class ModelManager : DrawableGameComponent
{
    List<BasicModel> models = new List<BasicModel>();

    public ModelManager(Game game) : base(game) { }    
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        models.Add(new BasicModel(Game.Content.Load<Model>(@"Models\track_new")));
        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; ++i)
                models[i].Update();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {       
        foreach (BasicModel bm in models)
            bm.Draw(((Game1)Game).camera);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Model.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.model.draw.aspx) method accepts a World and a View matrix - you should be able to specify a different World matrix for that model alone to achieve the effect required.